# Issue Comparing Access Column

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Can someone please explain to me when the "size" column wont work for comparison but I can replace the ID column in my code and it works perfectly fine. Perhaps my formatting of the access database column for Size isnt correct?

I am basically just trying to see if the key and value in my dictionary match the conditions in the access database and if so to write one text, if not write another. The error I keep getting when I have size in my code is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

[image]

```
For Each KeyPair In dict
        Dim key As String
        Dim value As Integer

        key = KeyPair.Key

        value = KeyPair.Value

        Dim sqlQry As String
        sqlQry = "SELECT Item, Size FROM [Table] WHERE Item = '" & key & "'AND Size>" & value & " "
       
        Console.WriteLine(sqlQry)

        Dim topDecision As String
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
        Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader
        myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If myreader.Read() Then
            topDecision = "Order"

        Else
            topDecision = "Dont"
        End If

        myreader.Close()


              Next
```

Comment: You're building your sql command using string concatenation, your the Size value your adding to the command is being converted to string and not a number.  Use parameters for the simple reason you can specify the correct types

Comment: Don't concatenate a space to value. Need a space between apostrophe and AND: `' AND `.

Comment: Is your table actually named Table?

Answer (score 1):

Connections and some other database objects provided by ADO.net use unmanaged code internally. They provide a `.Dispose` method where they release these resources. It is up to the coder to call the `.Dispose` method. Fortunately, .net provides `Using...End Using` blocks that handle this for us. Connections, commands and readers should be declared in the method where they are used so they can be properly closed and disposed.

Don't concatenate strings to build sql queries. **Use parameters** to avoid sql injection. We only need a single command and a single `ParametersCollection`. Only the values of the parameters change inside the loop.

A special note for OleDb parameters. The names of the parameters are ignored. The position of the parameter in the sql query should match the order that they are added to the `ParametersCollection`.

Declare `KeyPair` `As KeyValuePair` so you can access `.Key` and `.Value` properties.

I used a `StringBuilder` to collect the messages from your code. A `StringBuilder` is mutable (changeable) whereas a `String` is not. If I used a `String` the compiler would have to throw away a string and create a new one on each iteration. The garbage collector would be kept busy.

I used an interpolated string indicated by the `$` before the string. It allows us to insert variables directly into the string if they are surrounded by braces `{ }`.

If you follow this sample, be sure the text box at the end has `Multiline = True`.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim sqlQry = "SELECT Item, Size FROM [Table] WHERE Item = @Key AND Size > @Value;"
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Key", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", OleDbType.Integer)

        cn.Open()

        For Each KeyPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In dict
            cmd.Parameters("@Key").Value = KeyPair.Key
            cmd.Parameters("@Value").Value = KeyPair.Value
            Dim topDecision As String
            Using myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If myreader.Read() Then
                    topDecision = "Order"
                Else
                    topDecision = "Dont Order"
                End If
            End Using
            sb.AppendLine($"{KeyPair.Key} - {topDecision}")
        Next

    End Using
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly, same issue persists.. thanks for your efforts! Not sure what to do anymore with this

Comment: Try running your query inside of the Access application. See if you can get a better error description.

Comment: What are a few sample values from the Size field in the database and a few sample values of the .Value in the Dictionary?

Comment: You do have a space between Size and >. I see in your original query, you do not.

Comment: I have added the space, this did not do anything for me. My values in the Size of the database are whole integer values such as (1,200,234, 23, etc). While the dictionary values are of the same type, I thought perhaps there is a mismatch with my types between the two sets of data.. but it appears whatever i try it doesnt work

Comment: When I looked at your query I rather thought that the > should be a < . I not sure what size is but if you are wanting to order some item, I would think size might be referring to quantity on hand and the value in the dictionary is what customers are buying. This code is then checking on stock. If the Size is greater then the value in the dictionary then we order? Sounds backwards to me.

Comment: Did you try running the query from inside the Access applicaion?

Comment: Yes, I was able to finally figure it out once I wrote my data to the database and ran the query there. Not sure if you know what the difference would be verse just doing it in visual studio.

Comment: There should be no difference. I only suggested it because you might get a better error message. If you used the the Query designer, after the run you query you can select View all the way to the left on the ribbon menu. Choose SQL. You can copy and paste into your vb code as sqlQuery. Of course replace the parameter names with the literals.